# How to update fullscreen menu whenever browser window is resized?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My menu breaks when it is open and then the browser is resized, when you close the menu it closes the width of the old size browser, so if you open the menu and then increase the browser size and close the menu, you will still see some of the menu on the screen. I think I need to update the code whenever the browser is resized but not sure how.

Working example [here](https://codepen.io/gjjr/pen/PoRwvpB) (refresh the page with reduced browser width, open the menu, increase your browser width, then close the menu)

```js
const menuToggleOpen = document.querySelector("#menu-toggle-open");
const menuToggleClose = document.querySelector("#menu-toggle-close");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

const tl = gsap.timeline({
    paused: true
});

tl.to(".menu", {
  x: 0,
  duration: 0.6,
  ease: "expo.inOut"
});

tl.from(".menu nav a", {
  y: 40,
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 0.4,
  ease: "expo.out",
  stagger: 0.1
});

tl.from(".social", {
  y: 40,
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 0.4,
  ease: "expo.out"
});

menuToggleOpen.addEventListener("click", () => tl.play());
menuToggleClose.addEventListener("click", () => tl.reverse());
```

```css
#menu-toggle-open{
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Formula Condensed Light Italic", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-toggle-close{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Formula Condensed Light Italic", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.menu {
    height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: #d0ff00;
  color: #d0ff00;
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.menu a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: min(100% - 2rem, 70rem);
  height: 100%;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding-block: 2rem;
}

.menu nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-grow: 1;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.menu nav a {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Formula Condensed Light Italic", Sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 4vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
}


.social {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.fab{
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 2vw;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="menu-toggle-open">MENU</span>

<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-container">
      
      <span id="menu-toggle-close">CLOSE</span>

    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Work</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <div class="social">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    </nav>

    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to listen to resize events, and then tell the `tl` to play or reverse, to update the elements.

Comment: using something like `$(window).resize(function(){ });` ? Ive tried wrapping the code in that but it breaks it, could you detail exactly where it should go please?

Comment: its weird that this is happening because the menu sliding off to the left is being applied by CSS as you can see above `.menu{transform: translateX(-100vw);}` so i dont know why this isnt automatically updating when the browser is resized?

Comment: There's also `transform: translate(-629px, 0px);` applied to the element itself, which would need to be recalculated

Comment: That will be the "100vw", but its not being updated when the browser is resized. I have a feeling this may be an issue related to using GSAP

Comment: No, there is `transform: translate(-XXXpx, 0px);` On __the element itself__, not _only_ in the CSS. That's a calculated property that's been set by gsap.

Comment: Yes thats being set by the 100vw CSS though, then GSAP is using that to calculate, but its not updating on window resize which is what im trying to fix.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, the answer is to set the x position using GSAP instead of CSS:

```
const menuToggleOpen = document.querySelector("#menu-toggle-open");
const menuToggleClose = document.querySelector("#menu-toggle-close");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

gsap.set(".menu", { xPercent: -100 });

const tl = gsap.timeline({
  paused: true
});

tl.to(".menu", {
  xPercent: 0,
  duration: 0.6,
  ease: "expo.inOut"
});

tl.from(".menu nav a", {
  y: 40,
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 0.4,
  ease: "expo.out",
  stagger: 0.1
});

tl.from(".social", {
  y: 40,
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 0.4,
  ease: "expo.out"
});

menuToggleOpen.addEventListener("click", () => tl.play());
menuToggleClose.addEventListener("click", () => tl.reverse());
```